# Is it possible to send testnet eth from one testnet network to another?

Tags: ether, wallets, testnets, balances, transfer

Is it possible to send testnet eth from one testnet network to another? Curious because ain't getting much testnet eth these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible.
However, Ethereum test networks differ in consensus mechanism.

**Ropsten** is a Proof of Work (PoW) Test network, while
**Kovan, Goerli and Rinkeby** are Proof of Authority (PoA) Test networks.

Answer (score 0):

No that's not possible since they are independent. ETH are minted as a reward for miners and therefore always stay on the chain they were minted for.

(It could be that there is some kind of bridge for testnet ETH but i'm not aware of one.)

I had a good experience with the following faucets:

- Kovan, Rinkeby: [Chainlink Faucet](https://faucets.chain.link)